# Would a Moderator delete the misspelled [verliog] tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-blacklist-request

Would a Moderator please delete the misspelled [verliog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verliog) tag?

There is only one question with this tag: [Basic Verilog Assignment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/596650/basic-verilog-assignment)

The question title has the correct spelling of "Ver**il**og".  I can't tell when the "ver**li**og" tag was created, but I assume it was today when this question was posted.

The correct [verilog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verilog) tag should be added to the question.

I see no need to keep the misspelled version.  Please delete and blocklist it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for spotting this. As you said, it's clearly just a misspelling and not something that we need to consider with a full discussion, waiting for voting etc. I've replaced it with the correctly-spelled version of `verilog` on that question, as you suggested.

My reading of the mod documents on this, says that the misspelled `verliog` tag will automatically be deleted from the system, when a once-a-day job runs and sees that there are no questions with that tag.

We *could* get SE staff involved to add it to the blocklist (that is a staff-only function, mods can't add to the tag blocklist), but since this doesn't happen often, can I suggest that we don't add to the SE staff workload unless we *really* need to?

If you agree, then we would leave the work on this at confirming that the tag has been deleted by the same time tomorrow at the latest (I don't know the exact time each 24hrs that the empty tag delete function runs - I have seen a mention of 8-9 am UTC, but not 100% sure of that).

If this becomes a regular event then, yes, we can get SE staff to add it to the blocklist.

Comment: @toolic - Hi, FYI I have just confirmed that if someone starts typing `verl`, the misspelled `verliog` tag is no longer given as an option. It *was* shown yesterday when I did the same test. Therefore this confirms that the deletion-of empty tags function has run in the last 24 hrs, and has deleted that tag. Thanks for accepting this answer :-)